# Catalyst that combines oxygen and hydrogen

Tags: energy, catalysis, reaction-control

Are there any known catalysts that can combine hydrogen and oxygen into water?

Does this type of reaction have a name? Trying to search for information, it seems to be all about splitting hydrogen and oxygen, is there any work on combining these and some catalysts that could be used?

Comment: This looks like catalytic hydrogen combustion (CHC). Rarely needed, unless one needs to burn hydrogen in a more controlled manner without producing flames or explosion. I suggest searching Google Scholar with this keyword to get an idea what transition metals and their oxides are used in which cases.

Comment: @andselisk "Rarely needed" unless you want to generate clean electricity. This is what fuel cells do. Using exactly this reaction.

Comment: I have removed some of the comments, please discuss in [chat]. @matt_black

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

Not only is this possible it can be done while extracting electricity from the reaction. This is the key reaction in a hydrogen/oxygen fuel cell.

[Fuel cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell) have been known for well over a century and Hydrogen oxygen fuel cells have been used commercially since the 1930s. Platinum is often used as a catalyst for the key reaction in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Platinum is a good catalyst for this reaction. This technique is well known. It has been developed in the 19th century by Döbereiner.